# Eclipse does not show workspace to write code on

Tags: eclipse

i get the followng error when i create a new class. No code can be typed into the space, how can i fix this

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.getScrollbarsMode()I
```

the error log is as follows;

> Message;Unhandled event loop exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.getScrollbarsMode()I    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer$RulerLayout.layout(SourceViewer.java:130)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Composite.java:1263)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Composite.java:1249)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.layout(Composite.java:664)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.layout(Composite.java:622)  at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.source.CompositeRuler.layoutTextViewer(CompositeRuler.java:611)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.source.CompositeRuler.addDecorator(CompositeRuler.java:565)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer.addVerticalRulerColumn(SourceViewer.java:1194)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.source.projection.ProjectionSupport.doEnableProjection(ProjectionSupport.java:311)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.source.projection.ProjectionSupport$ProjectionListener.projectionEnabled(ProjectionSupport.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.source.projection.ProjectionViewer.fireProjectionEnabled(ProjectionViewer.java:487)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.source.projection.ProjectionViewer.enableProjection(ProjectionViewer.java:535)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaSourceViewer.setVisibleDocument(JavaSourceViewer.java:676)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.setDocument(TextViewer.java:2938)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer.setDocument(SourceViewer.java:642)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.source.projection.ProjectionViewer.setDocument(ProjectionViewer.java:374)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer.setDocument(SourceViewer.java:590)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.initializeSourceViewer(AbstractTextEditor.java:4030)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractTextEditor.java:3558)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.createPartControl(StatusTextEditor.java:54)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:440)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.createPartControl(JavaEditor.java:3098)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.createPartControl(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1505)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.makeActiveEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:1342)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActivePart(WorkbenchPage.java:1300)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.partAdded(WorkbenchPage.java:1780)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewFactory.createView(ViewFactory.java:173)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.showView(Perspective.java:2244)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyShowView(WorkbenchPage.java:1145)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$20.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3921)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:3918)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowViewHandler.openView(ShowViewHandler.java:162)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowViewHandler.execute(ShowViewHandler.java:76)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(CommandContributionItem.java:829)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.access$19(CommandContributionItem.java:815)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem$5.handleEvent(CommandContributionItem.java:805)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)

Comment: yes, but could not implement the suggested solution,

Comment: give us to see the error log

Comment: @Jeremy, i have edited and included the error log

Comment: Just a thought. Did you imported an existing project and then trying to create the class ?

Comment: Then I think it is very tough to tell you the exact issue. Why donot you try creating a new workspace and then import your project there? And see if that works.

Comment: I got same error. Please write solution here so i can do same. Thanks. Please add here.